# Will this "tree" cover all rational numbers in a range?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

#### Question

I am making a tree using the following two functions:

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{r},\quad g(x)=\frac{x+b}{r}$$

where $1<r<2$ and $0<b$ are rationals. Everything is a real number here.

The starting point is $x=0$. From here, we will compute $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ which will be the branches of $x=0$. We keep on repeating this process by composing the functions in every possible combination, e.g. $f(f(0))$ and $g(f(0))$ will be the branches of $f(0)$, and $f(g(0))$ and $g(g(0))$ will be the branches of $g(0)$, and so on. If we repeat this process $n$ times, we have $2^n$ branches.

My question is, will these tree branches eventually cover all rational numbers in a certain range?

#### Some headway

Intuitively, when $0<x<\frac{b}{r-1}$, $f(x)$ decreases $x$, whereas $g(x)$ increases $x$, i.e. $f(x)<x$ and $g(x)>x$.

Also, let's not consider all the branches off of $f(0)$, since $f(0)=0$ (it's the same as the starting point $x=0$.) Therefore the real branching starts at the point $g(0)=b/r$.

Now let's consider the branch path where we keep on applying $g(\cdot)$. The $n$ number of compositions would be

$$ b\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{r^i}$$

which converges to $\frac{b}{r-1}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, the extremities of the tree are $0$ and $\frac{b}{r-1}$, which sets the range.

I guess a related or sub-question is: can there even be branches that have the same value?

Comment: I take it $b$ and $r$ are meant to be rationals, else you're not likely to get many rationals out of your procedure.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Note too that for each $r$ all values of $b$ are equivalent (just scale $x$).
$$ $$
Some irrational values of $r$ yield coincident branches, e.g. $g(0) = f(g(g(0)))$ iff $r$ is the golden ratio.  You may be able to show that this can't happen for rational $r \in (1,2)$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies The golden ratio case is interesting. Is it intuitive that coincident branches can't happen for rational $r\in(1,2)$?

Comment: I had assumed when reading this that $b,r$ need not be rationals. If $b,r\in\mathbb{Q}$ we cannot obtain any fraction with prime denominator not dividing the denominator of $b$ or the numerator of $r$, right? (For irrational $b,r$ maybe one can obtain all the rationals by some Baire argument)

Comment: @Saúl RM there's surely no way to obtain *all* rationals.  Any time you get a rational value you get a polynomial in $b$ and $r$.  With enough such relations you can solve for $b,r$ as algebraic numbers.  Then there's an integer $N$ such that both $Nb$ and $N/r$ are algebraic integers, and you can never reach any rational whose denominator contains a prime not dividing $N$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies That makes sense, also my Baire idea didn't work. But isn't the main question solved anyways?

Comment: Indeed it is . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main Question is answered in the negative by @Saúl RM in the comments.
We answer the sub-question
"can there even be branches that have the same value?":
not for any rational $r$ other than $1$ and $-1$
(neither of which is in the allowed range $1 < r < 2$).

Indeed the "branches" are precisely the sums of finite subsets of
$\{ b/r, b/r^2, b/r^3, \ldots, b/r^n, \ldots, \}$.
(Proof: by induction on $n$, after $n$ steps we have the $2^n$ subsets of
$\{ b/r, b/r^2, b/r^3, \ldots, b/r^n \}$.)  So, some two branches coincide
if and only if $P(r) = 0$ for some nonzero polynomial $P$
each of whose coefficients is $0$ or $\pm 1$.
But such $P$ cannot have any rational roots other than
$0$ (which is not allowed because $r$ is the denominator of $f$ and $g$)
and $\pm 1$.  **QED**